# Identifying this unusual tree

Tags: identification, trees, wildflowers

I photographed this unusual-looking bush/tree growing wild in central Texas in December of last year:

[image]
[image: closeup]

It had beige-colored, spiky flowers/seed heads arranged in panicles (at least I think that's the right terminology). It had grown to about seven or eight feet tall. Does anyone know what kind of tree this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a Buckwheat, if it's already flowered and pics are of seed pods. For tree/shrub ID, pic from a distance, pic of bark, pic of leaf arrangement, info on what it's done this year so far, your location - all useful.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I stumbled upon this tree while on a hike, so I know nothing about its history. Like I said it was December, so it seems likely that it had bloomed earlier and those are just the seed heads.